# JSON object returning wrong number in struct

Tags: json, go, types

I have created a struct for an API I am getting a total price back from. That number is something like 93.6400000000000005684341886080801486968994140625 I have set the type in the struct for that to be float64 but when accessing the data once it is parsed to the struct the number turns into something like 2664 or something completely wrong and in the thousands. Is it the wrong type I am using or something else?

Comment: It's impossible to debug code we can't see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what did you do to get the data but this code gets the data back with the exact precision

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type Bill struct {
    Total float64 `json:"total"`
}

func main() {
    data := []byte(`{"total": 93.6400000000000005684341886080801486968994140625}`)

    var b Bill

    err := json.Unmarshal(data, &b)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%.100f", b.Total)
}
```

Comment: Turns out the APIis returning the wrong number but returns it right in Postman? Very weird bug. Thanks for the reply! EDIT: I must have something wrong in the code requesting the API. Fixing it now.